# .NET Core DI Child Scope with Db Context

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

(I am writing a processor that handles requests in a queue (console app).

I would like to use the .NET Core DI.

So far my code looks like this:

```
...
var connectionString = exportConfiguration.ConnectionString;

using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
   var service = provider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();

   service.SqlConnectionString = sqlConnectionString; // I don't think property injection on a dbcontext will work, it takes its connection string in via the constructor
}
```

I have read how to assign parameters to the object as shown above, but how do I create a new context based on the connection string that is used in all the objects that the service uses (using constructor injection because thats why dbcontexts take - connection string in constructor)?

(I am not storing my connection string in the queue by the way, a code comes down the queue and my app then chooses the connection string to use).

Comment: Will need more context(details) to understand what it is you are actually trying to achieve. The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear and might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Have you read [how to configure your DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)? If so, why doesn't this answer your question? What is different from what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have edited to use a dbcontext in the example rather than a service. The problem is the context is already created. This is a common problem for example if you are processing queue items in a processor method, and the connection string/database could be different for each queue item. I can't create multiple methods, one for each database in this case, because the queue needs throttling to one at a time because it calls a powerbi service later on that can only process one request at a time - so I need one process to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to work this out. The key was that when you use CreateScope(), then GetRequiredService(), the DI system will provide new objects. So I just had to provide the correct information. This is now what my code looks like:

```
// Prior code gets information from a queue, which could be different every time.
// This needs passing as a constructor to the DbContext and possibly other information from the queue to other methods constructors
// (constructor injection not property injection)

var connectionString = queueItem.ConnectionString;

// save the connection string so the DI system (startup.cs) can pick it up
Startup.ConnectionString = connectionString;

using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;

   var service = provider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

   // go off and get data from the correct dbcontext / connection string
   var data = service.GetData();

   // more processing
}

/// The Service has the DbContext in its constructor:
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private DbContext _dbContext;
    public MyService(DbContext dbContext) {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // more stuff that uses dbcontext
}

/// In startup.cs:
public static string ConnectionString {get;set;}
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Startup.ConnectionString));

// Also the following code will work if needed:
// Parameter1 is something that comes from the queue and could be different for each
// CreateScope()
build.Services.AddScoped<IMyOtherService>((_) => 
   new MyOtherService(Startup.Parameter1));
```

I hope this helps somebody, because when I was googling around I couldn't find out how to do this.